# Knowledge base or blog platform for developers

Tags: knowledge-base, blog

My goal is to document the issues I'm facing. E.g. I upgrade `ruby` to `2.7` and something breaks. I document the symptoms, the cause, the solution, add the relevant tags. So that later I could come back and deal with the issue more quickly. And possibly link to it.

I don't consider starting a blog, since I believe that takes more time. I need something more sketchy. Primarily for myself, but it can be public.

Requirements:

- an easy way to add articles
- a list of articles ordered by date (in a blog-like manner)
- some sort of markdown to write the articles
- tags and probably categories
- full text-search within a category (or constrained by tags)

Minimalistic (lightweight) interface would be a plus. In terms of page load, amount of javascript needed to render a page.

An online solution is probably preferable, but a self-hosted one would probably also do. Unless I need to run some resource-intensive software like, supposedly, Elasticsearch or some Java software.

Probably something like https://gist.github.com/ but with tags and search capabilities.

Comment: https://jekyllrb.com/ is a static site generator thhat has built-in blogging capabilities and should be able to do everything (except maybe the full text search). its compatible with github pages if easy hosting is a priority

Comment: I regret mentioning "knowledge base." In my defense I can only say I didn't know what to expect. That is probably the reason I gave a broader phrasing, to avoid being left with no suggestions. But my priorities are generally, "blog is preferred over wiki, online service over self-hosted solution." I could probably change the question, but that would most likely make the answers less relevant.

Comment: if youre looking for an online service blog solution, i'd still say jekyll is a lot closer to "online service" (if you host on github pages) than something "self-hosted" if youre familiar with github. you pretty much put your jekyll site in a github repository and turn on github pages and it hets automatically hosted for you. Theres also a few blogging platforms out there like wordpress that can help provide the "online service + blog" functionality for free as well

Comment: Well, I suspected you can do that with Jekyll. Another alternative would probably be [Vercel](https://vercel.com/). At least it let's one turn their repository into a site. The wiki solutions and Wordpress... they might be good. But for some reason I feel like avoiding them. Let's call it a personal bias. For now I'm experimenting with GitHub Gist. More on it in [my other comment](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/77763/knowledge-base-or-blog-platform-for-developers?noredirect=1#comment95792_77766).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Read the Docs](https://readthedocs.org/) is the more appropriate I've seen for this.

Here you can see their own documentation: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good opportunity for a wiki. It's been a while since I looked into wikis, but when I did, I particularly liked [DokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) as it was easy to implement and seemed well suited to documentation. It supports blogs via plugins such as [blog](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:blog?s%5B%5D=blog) or [blogtng](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:blogtng?s%5B%5D=blog). [WikiMatrix](https://www.wikimatrix.org) is a nice site for comparing wiki options and you may find a better option there.

Comment: Do you think it makes sense to run a full-fledged wiki? It appears there's [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5537451/52499) to search capabilities of GitHub Gist than I thought. And there's also [Lapton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45723556/52499).

Comment: I can’t answer that, but many wikis are quite light weight and easy to use.